# Complex-valued spacetime curvature

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, curvature, complex-numbers, tachyon

I've just been reading about tachyons and tachyonic fields, and although they probably don't exist/are wildly unstable, I'm curious: What does imaginary mass do to spacetime curvature? Does ‘complex valued curvature’ even have a single plausible meaning the way real-valued curvature does?

Comment: @BenRW Specifically, since you have enough reputation to access [chat], you might want to start by going there and getting some feedback about the question. If there's a way to clarify it that would make it more likely to get reopened, someone there is likely to suggest it. You can also get feedback on whether you should make a meta post and, if so, how to phrase it.

Comment: For anyone reading this later: Comments on chat included the suggestion I search for "complex relativity" or some variant of that. Probably more useful for search results than how I phrased it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notion of complex curvature does exist: see [Y. Martinez-Maure, Real and complex hedgehogs, their symplectic area,curvature and evolutes](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-02948386/document). For instance, a complex circle with (complex) radius R has a (complex) radius of curvature equal to R (see page 17).

The author says the paper is to appear in the Journal of Symplectic Geometry.